# python pandas - generating view/copy warning filtering dataframe with multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, filter, copy

I know this has been written about ad nauseum, and this link has been cited repeatedly ( [pandas: Returning a view versus a copy](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) ), but I cannot seem to write this simple line without getting the warning. It's making me insane, my syntax appears to look like the suggestions.

```
df['A'][(df['B']>=10) & (df['B']<50)] = 'group1'
```

Would someone please shed some light on what error I am making?

Comment: In addition to the answer, you can also do `df['A'] = np.where(  condition, 'group1', value_if_false )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the example suggests, use `.loc` and put both column and row conditions in the same subscription:

```
df.loc[(df['B']>=10) & (df['B']<50), 'A'] = 'group1'
```

Any time you have two sets of brackets, like `blah[...][...]`, you are doing chained indexing.  To avoid chained indexing, you need to get all your conditions into a single set of brackets.

Comment: Sorry BrenBarn, I meant to add that I had tried df.ix[:,'A'][...] but your explanation makes sense.